# pgAdmin4 doesn't open on mac

Tags: macos, pgadmin-4, macos-big-sur

Hello I am trying to use postgresql for a project so I have installed some tools that was suggested. But I cant run pgAdmin4, it doesn't open. In fact it doesn't do anything. No elephant symbol on panel, no default browser opening. However in activity monitor it shows that it is running and uses more than 99 percent if CPU. After a while it crashes and becomes "doesnt respond"

I have MacBook Pro mid 2014 running Big Sur 11.1
I have the latest version of postgresql 13 (I installed it from the website)
I am using Python 3.9
and also psycopg2 2.8.6 (if that matters)

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Had this problem with pgAdmin4 v6.17 on mac OS 10.13. Downgraded to Pgadmin4 v6.15 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with version 7.5.
I used the 7.4 version since it was released 1 month prior and it worked.
So downloading the previous version might help you.